# Flutter Container's BoxConstrains not working as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

this is the code

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(100, 100)),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellow),
    child: Card(child: Text('Hello World')),
  ),
);
```

what i expected is `Card` is 100 x 100, but it's not, it just stretched to the whole screen. why does it happened?

[image: container not working as i expected]

Comment: Wrap the Container in a Center or Align

Comment: it works, but why?

Comment: You try to force a constraint that is not possible. The container is forced full size by the parent.

Comment: so the constraints is applied to itself, gotcha, thank you~

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Flutter team released a great article named ["Understanding constraints"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints) that's definitely worth checking out if you're unsure about how constraints work.
That being said, here's a more in-depth answer specifically about your problem:

**Why do your `BoxConstraint`s get ignored?**

The `Container` internally creates a `ConstrainedBox` in order to enforce your constraints.
The `ConstrainedBox`'s `RenderObject` - a `RenderConstrainedBox` - then tries to adhere to your constraints as much as possible.

During layout, the following code [taken from the `RenderConstrainedBox` implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart) is executed.
The members `minWidth`, `maxWidth`, `minHeight` and `maxHeight` stem from your given constraints, while `constraints` are the constraints provided by the Flutter framework (in your case, the screen size).

```
BoxConstraints(
  minWidth: minWidth.clamp(constraints.minWidth, constraints.maxWidth),
  maxWidth: maxWidth.clamp(constraints.minWidth, constraints.maxWidth),
  minHeight: minHeight.clamp(constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight),
  maxHeight: maxHeight.clamp(constraints.minHeight, constraints.maxHeight)
)
```

Because the screen size is inflexible, the `constraints` are tight, meaning `constraints.minWidth == constraints.maxWidth` and `constraints.minHeight == constraints.maxHeight`.
That forces `clamp` to ignore your constraints (for example, `2.clamp(3,3) == 3`).

So there you have it:
The constraints you give to a `Container` will only be respected as much as possible.
Because the whole screen needs to be filled, the `Container` is forced to take the tight screen constraints, thereby ignoring your constraints.

**What to do about it**

To make it possible for the `Container` to respect your constraints, you have to give it more "breathing room", i.e. don't force it to fill the screen.
A simple solution would be to wrap it in a `Center`, but it depends on your preferences on where the `Container` should be aligned.

Comment: Im in similar setup as poster of the question. My BoxConstraints gives half of screen heigth to Container's content. This is more than enough for the content. And the constriant is of course ignored. Yes, "What to do about it" is working but to me this weird flutter logic is too counter intutitive to be useful for someone coming from native development.